# Coordinating Job containers and Volumes in a CI system

Tags: kubernetes

I'm working on a tinker Kubernetes-based CI system, where each build gets launched as a Job. I'm running these much like Drone CI does, in that each step in the build is a separate container. In my k8s CI case, I'm running each step as a container within a Job pod. Here's the behavior I'm after:

1. A build volume is created. All steps will mount this. A Job is fired
   off with all of the steps defined as separate containers, in order of
   desired execution.
2. The git step (container) runs, mounting the shared volume and cloning 
   the sources.
3. The 'run tests' step mounts the shared volume to a container spawned
   from an image with all of the dependencies pre-installed.
4. If our tests pass, we proceed to the Slack announcement step, which is
   another container that announces our success.

I'm currently using a single Job pod with an emptyDir Volume for the shared build space. I did this so that we don't have to wait while a volume gets shuffled around between nodes/Pods. This also seemed like a nice way to ensure that things get cleaned up automatically at build exit.

The problem becomes that if I fire up a multi-container Job with all of the above steps, they execute at the same time. Meaning the 'run tests' step could fire before the 'git' step.

I've thought about coming up with some kind of logic in each of these containers to sleep until a certain unlock/"I'm done!" file appears in the shared volume, signifying the dependency step(s) are done, but this seems complicated enough to ask about alternatives before proceeding.

I could see giving in and using multiple Jobs with a coordinating Job, but then I'm stuck getting into Volume Claim territory (which is a lot more complicated than emptyDir).

To sum up the question:

Is my current approach worth pursuing, and if so, how to sequence the Job's containers? I'm hoping to come up with something that will work on AWS/GCE *and* bare metal deployments.

I'm hesitant to touch PVCs, since the management and cleanup bit is not something I want my system to be responsible for. I'm also not wanting to require networked storage when emptyDir could work so well.

*Edit: Please don't suggest using another existing CI system, as this isn't helpful. I am doing this for my own gratification and experimentation. This tinker CI system is unlikely to ever be anything but my toy.*

Comment: Just curious if you took a look at https://fabric8.io/. Sounds like everything you are trying to achieve is mostly coded in there. Short of using that directly, maybe some of their examples related to CI/CD could give you ideas on how to achieve what you are trying to do?

Comment: It looks like they use Jenkins for this sort of thing instead of Kubernetes directly, so probably not. It was a good thought, though!

Comment: There is a way to setup Jenkins using k8s. See https://github.com/kubernetes/charts/tree/master/stable/jenkins

Comment: I'm writing a toy CI system with Kubernetes directly. This means not using Jenkins, fabric8, or anything other than straight Kubernetes. Mostly for giggles and to see how well things would map.

Comment: I would say that you are taking an unorthodox approach to CI. I am hesitant to reply because there are always a 100 ways of doing one thing but I thing for sure is that your idea of using a file flag to sync containers is not good.

What is the background reasoning behind wanting to isolate each step in different containers? That sounds like more of a hassle than anything.

Comment: @Frank.Germain
 
"is not good" isn't especially useful without details. Ready and willing to listen.


Per-container step isolation has worked magnificently with Drone CI, so I'd like to continue that pattern with my toy CI. It makes plugin authorship easy and language-agnostic. I can also re-use the whole base of existing plugins, since they are just Docker images.

Comment: Edited the question to more explicitly point out that I'm specifically not wanting to use an existing CI systems. I'm doing this for science.

Comment: @Greg: Let's use use humor to make a point here: There hasn't been once in history of man when someone developed a system and used a shared file based flag system to sync external processes where other developers looked at it and said "WOW, this is really easy to understand and use!" and never once where someone said "Damned, I couldn't think of a better way to accomplish the same thing". I think you need to look at a "Controller" container that starts inside your pod that's able to read some metadata about the job and sync the child container execution by using the host docker process.

Answer (score 0):

If you want all the build steps to run in containers, [GitLab CI](https://about.gitlab.com/gitlab-ci/) or [Concourse CI](https://concourse.ci/) would probably be a much better fit for you. I don't have experience with [fabric8.io](https://fabric8.io/), but [Frank.Germain](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1030430/frank-germain) suggests that it will also work.

Once you start getting complex enough that you need signaling between containers to order the build steps it becomes much more productive to use something pre-rolled.

As an option you could use a static volume (i.e. a [host path](http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/volumes/#hostpath) as an artifact cache, and trigger the next container in sequence from the current container, mounting the same volume between the stages. You could then just add a step to the beginning or end of the build to 'clean up' after your pipeline has been run.

**To be clear:** *I don't think that rolling your own CI is the most effective way to handle this, as there are already systems in place that will do exactly what you are looking for*

Comment: Again, I'm doing this as a tinker project. "Use GitLab or Concourse" is not helpful.

Comment: I know, that is why I gave you an actual solution ;) It was more as a warning in case someone comes across this in search for a CI solution.

Comment: This sounds potentially like my emptyDir approach above, but I'm not 100% sure. My thought was for all steps to mount the emptyDir at start time. Each container would know which other steps it was dependent on, and would sleep in postStart until all of the dependent unlock files are present in the emptyDir. We'd stop sleeping and let execution continue beyond postStart. Is this in essence what you are suggesting? I wasn't sure what you meant by "trigger".